# Are a block and a compound statement the same concept?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

In the C11 standard

> 6.8  Statements and blocks
>
> A block allows a set of declarations and statements to be grouped
> into one syntactic unit.
>
> 6.8.2  Compound statement Syntax
>
> ```
> compound-statement:
> { block-item-listopt }
>
> block-item-list:
> block-item
> block-item-list  block-item
>
> block-item:
> declaration
> statement
> Semantics
> ```
>
> A compound statement is a block.
>
> 6.9.1  Function deﬁnitions
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> function-deﬁnition:
> declaration-speciﬁers declarator  declaration-listopt compound-statement
> ```

So  a compound statement is a block.

Is a block a compound statement?

In a function definition, does the part "compound-statement" mean the same as a block?

Comment: If you just Ctrl-F the standard text it says iteration statements are blocks...

Comment: Tim, it brings me no joy at all to see you banned again, it really does not. I appreciate that you have indicated previously that you would rather I did not comment on your posts, and I have abided by that request until now. I understand you are fastidiously sticking to your view that you have been mistreated, including by this new ban, and I am convinced you have brought it upon yourself. I wonder if you would care to email me, via the details in my profile, so I can explain this to you privately.

Comment: I am conscious that you don't believe you need this advice, but I am quite certain you do. Whether you are welcome to post at Stack Overflow is probably a trivial matter - this kind of drama affects your employability too. A change of course is essential if you want to work happily with others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A compound-statement is a block, but it's not the only thing which is a block. An iteration statement is also a block, for example (6.8.5/5), even if the loop body consists of a simple statement.

The syntax of a function definition, unlike an iteration statement, requires braces. A compound-statement is a syntactic category which is surrounded by braces.

A block is a semantic category, used to specify the scope of names and the lifetime of automatic objects.

Comment: Is an iteration-statement not a compound-statement?

Comment: 6.8.2 shows what a `compound-statment` is: an open brace, optionally a `block-list`, and a close brace. That's not even vaguely similar to the syntax of any `iteration-statement`, all of which start with keywords, not punctuation.